# Output data from an associative array

Tags: php

I've stored countries with their codes in an array like below

```
$countries = array (
    'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
    'AX' => 'Åland Islands',
    'AL' => 'Albania',
    'DZ' => 'Algeria'
);
```

Suppose I got the country code 'AF' or country name 'Afghanistan' from a form, how do I output both the code and name from the array?

The output I'm trying to get is: Afghanistan AF. I'll later use that in code below.

```
echo $countries['AF'] gives me the country name, but how do I output both;
```

Comment: echo 'AF' . $countries['AF']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the code ('AF' in this case

```
$code = 'AF';
echo 'Country :', $countries[$code], " has code $code\n";
```

But if you want to got the other way i.e. Afghanistan to get the code AF, you have to iterate throught the list or construct another array.

Comment: This is close to what I wanted :-)

Answer (score 1):

for your satisfaction `key($countries['AF'])` gives you the key which is AF itself :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
var_dump(array_slice($countries, array_search('AX', array_keys($countries)), 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your question but if you are asking about iterating the array to output both code and name, you just assign the key within the loop:

```
foreach ($countries as $code => $name) {
       echo "$code : $name";
}
```

The other solution is to flip the array, if you only know the country name submitted in the form you are talking about.

```
$countries = array_flip($countries); // Flips the array so Code => Name is Name => Code
$code = $countries[$_POST['country']]; // Where $_POST['country'] is the name
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe with a loop

```
 <?php
     foreach($countries as $key=>$name) {
         echo "<p>$key => $name</p>";
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach($countries as $key=>value)
{
 echo "Code: ".$key." Country: ".$value;
}
```